# regex match() fails to catch a simple pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, arabic

I am trying to work with some simple regex functions in Python. I am using regex to catch patterns in the Arabic alphabet, but it doesn't seem to be working in the simplest cases when one adds a few letters at the beginning of a pattern, regardless of whether there is a ligature or not:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'ترينهايمان')
>>> p.match('به ترينهايمان')
>>>


>>> p = re.compile(r'ترینهایمان')
>>> p.match('بهترینهایمان') 
>>>
```

The longer string is basically the pattern itself with two letters added at the beginning.

AFAIK, match should have returned a value, but it doesn't.

and it's curious because when you add a letter to the end of the pattern it catches it:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'ترينهايمان')
>>> p.match('ترينهايماني')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02C52FA8>
>>> p.match('بهترينهايمان')
>>>
```

Comment: What are the actual characters there?  That is, do the strings contain the same characters display differently, or do they actually contain different characters.  If the strings actually contain different characters (medial vs initial forms), then they are different characters and won't match.

Comment: به + ترینهایمان = بهترینهایمان
The characters are all the same. They don't have different ascii numbers. Take the first two initial letters (به) off of the longer string to get to the shorter one. The match function should logically recognize the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.match` will only match patterns that start at the beginning of the string:

> **re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)**
>
> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note
>   that this is different from a zero-length match.

Since you're trying to match a string with extra characters at the beginning, `match` won't recognize the string as a match. You need to use `re.search` instead.

Comment: This was confusing me quite a bit at first, before I remembered Arabic is a right-to-left language. :)

Comment: You are awesome, dano! Just before I read the answer I'd realized that this had nothing to do with the Arabic alphabet as this was not working with English either. You saved me hours of frustration!