# Programmatically determine where Python's re.match stopped matching

Tags: python, regex

I need to determine where in a string `re.match` stopped matching; for a simplistic example:

```py
import re
abc = re.compile(r"[ab]+c$")

m = abc.match("baac")
# Matches, yay!

f1 = abc.match("badc")
# Match fails at index 2
# I.e. the string is actively rejected

f2 = abc.match("babb")
# Match fails after the end of the string
# I.e. the string is consumed before a match is accepted, but it wasn't rejected
```

I'm trying to programmatically distinguish between the `f1` and `f2` failure modes to find out if a string could be the beginning of a potential match or can be ruled out as rejected.

Update: I know `re.match` doesn’t tell me why it didn’t match, I’m trying to figure out how to get that information from the underlying engine somehow

Comment: re.match will return None if it't doesn't found anything so you can just check the result is None or not [fail regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771754/11225821)

Comment: My question is “how can I tell _why_ the match failed?”, I know `re.match` returns `None` if it doesn’t match, but I need more information than that.

Comment: well that how it response to a fail match [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match), if you want to understand how it work then maybe search through the regex code of python on their github page

Comment: Yup, I'm diving into the code, but I ask in case someone has already done something like this and could point me in the right direction.  Thanks anyway, though.