# Unable to search simple pattern in string

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

Unable to guess why this is returning `None` eventhough string containing "-pg:2Fetchotp for login:" pattern is found within str1:

```
import re
str1='1592029830201;12:00:30-bid:6--pg:2Fetchotp for login: 70300002358'
ret = re.match('-pg:2Fetchotp for login:\s+(\d{10})',str1)
print(ret)
```

Comment: That `}` looks out of place - you probably want a `*` or `+` there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex match() fails to catch a simple pattern in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771389/regex-match-fails-to-catch-a-simple-pattern-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.match` matches the beginning of the string and doesn't search for the pattern in whole string. Also, there's a typo in your regex. Try the following:

```
import re
str1='1592029830201;12:00:30-bid:6--pg:2Fetchotp for login: 70300002358'
ret = re.match('.*-pg:2Fetchotp for login:\s+(\d{10})',str1)
print(ret)
```

With `.*` added, the regex can be matches the string starting from the beginning. And so the match is complete string in this case. Otherwise you can also use `re.search` which searches the string for first match:

```
import re
str1='1592029830201;12:00:30-bid:6--pg:2Fetchotp for login: 70300002358'
ret = re.search('-pg:2Fetchotp for login:\s+(\d{10})',str1)
print(ret)
```